# Regular grid for whole planet

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, grids-graticules, mercator

I`m trying to generate rectangular grid for whole world with fixed cell size in 350 meters (width and height are equals).

What i tried to do:
1) in main loop iterate trough longitude in range [-180; 180]
2) in nested loop iterate trough latitude in range [-85.06; 85.06] (Web mercator bounds)
3) increment cells bound to 350 meters on East (n main loop) and North (in nested loop) using GeographicLib **Geodesic.WGS84.Direct()**.

Java code:

```
    double lon_min = -180;
    double lon_max = 180;
    double lat_min = -85.06;
    double lat_max = 85.06;

    double lon_max_c = lon_min;
    double lon_min_c = lon_min;

    int grid_x = 0;
    int grid_y = 0;
    int cell_id = 0;

    while(lon_max_c < lon_max)
    {
        double lat_min_c = lat_min;
        double lat_max_c = lat_min;

        lon_min_c = lon_max_c;
        GeodesicData g = Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(lat_min_c, lon_min_c, 90, 350);

        boolean isXlast = g.lon2 > lon_max || (lon_min_c > 0 && g.lon2 < 0);
        lon_max_c = isXlast? lon_max : g.lon2;

        grid_y = 0;

        while(lat_max_c < lat_max)
        {
            lat_min_c = lat_max_c;

            GeodesicData g1 = Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(lat_min_c, lon_min_c, 0, 350);

            boolean isYlast = g1.lat2 > lat_max;
            lat_max_c = isYlast? lat_max : g1.lat2;

            System.out.print("\rid: " +  cell_id + " lon: " + lon_max_c + " lat: " + lat_max_c);

            grid_y = grid_y + 1;
            cell_id = cell_id + 1;
        }
        grid_x = grid_x + 1;
    }
```

As a result, ~530 million cells were generated.
Howewer, area of whole planet is ~510 squared meters. So, the total number of cells should be about 4 billion.
What is wrong? What should I do to solve the problem correctly?

Comment: It isn't possible to create a rectangular grid that covers the Earth, because the Earth isn't rectangular. Each polygon is a spheroidal trapezoid.

Comment: Translate meters into fractional degrees 350 m = 0.003149748...

Comment: The cells with a size of 350x350 meters with your limitations should be greater than 6,168,787,341, if I'm not mistaken :-), these are rough calculations of cells measuring 360x170 degrees ...

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53342859/openstreetmap-rectangular-grid-for-whole-planet

Answer (score 1):

> rectangular grid for whole world with fixed cell size in 350 meters (width and height are equals)

What you are trying to do is impossible as Earth is not a rectangle. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection for starting point to learn more.

While this effect can be ignored for small areas, on scale like "longitude in range [-180; 180]", "latitude in range [-85.06; 85.06]" ignoring it is not feasible.